# Access List flutter from one dart to another

Tags: list, flutter

How to access variable availableList below from one dart to another

```
class Excerciselist extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;

  Excerciselist( this.value );
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyExc();  }
}

ImageSequenceAnimatorState imageSequenceAnimator;

void onReadyToPlay(ImageSequenceAnimatorState _imageSequenceAnimator) {
  imageSequenceAnimator = _imageSequenceAnimator;
}
final List<Exercise> availableList = [
  Exercise(
      name: "Pushups",
      imageUrl: "imagesfirst",
      duration: "20"),
  Exercise(
      name: "Chinups",
      imageUrl: "second",
      duration: "20"),
  Exercise(
```

how can i access availableList variable in another dart file?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Excerciselist {

  String name;
  String imageUrl;
  String duration;

  Excerciselist({
    this.name,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.duration,
  });

  static List<Excerciselist> availableList = [
    Excerciselist(name: "Pushups", imageUrl: "imagesfirst", duration: "20"),
    Excerciselist(name: "Chinups", imageUrl: "second", duration: "20"),
  ];
}
```

then import it to you file and you can list the items, for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Excerciselist.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  List _list = Excerciselist.availableList;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
          children: [
        ..._list.map((data) {
          return Column(
            children: [Text('${data.name}'), Text('${data.imageUrl}')],
          );
        })
      ].toList()),
    ));
  }
}
```

================

you can also create an instance and methods for manipulating you data, for example to find the total duration.

```
class Excerciselist {

// adding these two lines
  static Excerciselist instance = Excerciselist._();
  Excerciselist._();
// ==

  String name;
  String imageUrl;
  String duration;

  Excerciselist({
    this.name,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.duration,
  });


  static List<Excerciselist> availableList = [
    Excerciselist(name: "Pushups", imageUrl: "imagesfirst", duration: "20"),
    Excerciselist(name: "Chinups", imageUrl: "second", duration: "20"),
  ];

// Create the method

  durationOf() {
    int totalDur = 0;
    availableList.forEach((element) {
      totalDur = totalDur + int.parse(element.duration);
    });
    return totalDur;
  }


//
}
```

and you can call it in your main file:

`Excerciselist <name> = Excerciselist.instance;`

then use it in your widget: `<name>.durationOf()`

Comment: Sure!, I've added some updates to the comment, I'm a new programmer, so I bet that you might fine other ways to be best, maybe take a look at Riverpod -as Da Bot said-

Answer (score 0):

import this file like mak said.

Making use of State management solutions like riverpod and provider will be more cleaner.